# Backbone Cookie Issue

Tags: rest, backbone.js

> Hi,
>   I am a newbie to backbone and working on rest api's, I am working on saving a model, the api call and update is working fine, but handling the response in the success call back function i get the error '**Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'cookie' property from 'Document': Access is denied for this document**'.The issue is on chrome. The response code is also 200 but still the success call back does not fire.
>
> Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
eventModel.save({},{
                  dataType:"text",
                 wait :true,
                  success : function(eventModel,response){
                      try{
                      console.log(document.cookie);

                  }catch (err){
                 console.log(err.message);
             }
                  },
                  error : function(eventModel,response){

                  }


              })
```

Comment: Please post the code of your success-function

Comment: > Please Find The Code Below..

Comment: Are you using an iframe?

Comment: No Am not using.. That 'console.log(document.cookie)' is just a plain statement. am neither setting nor reading a cookie.

Comment: you cannot read that document property at that point. A common error when using iframes. Do you want to test something with backbone or why do you need a cookie?

Comment: I have to handle the response in the success call back function like, notifying the user the action was successful, am not using iframes. I dont need a cookie, am not setting or reading any, the success call function is not getting executed..

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing the error on `document.cookie`, which means the `success` function is triggered but since this causes a runtime error the script stops.

Try this

```
success : function(eventModel,response){
    alert('Saved successfuly');
}
```